# How to set an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to only allow one certain computer

Tags: node.js, http-headers

I have a some node.js code in a glitch server (not in my own computer) :

```js
let http = require("http");
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Allow-Access-Control-Origin": "http://my-localhost-IP-Address"
  });
  res.end(someData)
})
```

That doesn't seem to work for me.
I can't do it from my localhost, nor can I do it in the `file:` protocol, but I can make it by simply typing the url in the browser.

Setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `http://localhost` doesn't work either.

> Is there a way I can set the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to only allow some specific computers to access it.

**Note:** Again, the code is in a server in the internet, not in my own computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CORS**

```
let cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors(), function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
```

In this, you can also add multiple URLs.

Comment: While I appreciate this answer, won't this allow `localhost:4200` from any computer?

Comment: This is just for an example. I had already added a comment please go through it. You have replace IP address with the IP address you want to request from